# Google chrome freezes when printing a page using window print method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

I have latest google chrome version -`32.0.1700.107 m` installed on windows 8 machine.

I am doing this:

```
popup = window.open();
popup.print();
```

This opens a new popup and a print window appears. Now, when I go back to the page from where I triggered this, it freezes and I cannot do anything there.

Here is the small fiddle for your reference. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vQEhQ/1/)

Click the button and come back to the fiddle page (do not close the print page) and try typing anything in the fiddle, it will be hanged and as soon as you will close the print page, the fiddle window will get normal.

This is in Google chrome ONLY, other browsers are working smoothly. Please help.

I tried:

1. Opening the popup in new window using `window.open("","","width=800,height=600")`.
2. Putting `popup.close()`.
3. opening it on some different OS (windows 7, XP)

But got no success

Please some kind soul help me with this issue or some work around.

Comment: I have no issue in printing. When print window pops up, then the window which triggered this will freeze. And when you close the print pop up, the window becomes normal again.

Comment: yes, parent window is not freezing, it is fine

Comment: @user8888 May be someone else would be able to reproduce the same problem. I have now tested this on ubuntu 12.04 also, so this is the problem of chrome. One more thing I would like to ask, when you open the print window, does it appear as a popup box or new tab opens and in that print options are given?

Comment: Also, are you able to type inside the fiddle sections?

Comment: @user8888 I found a work around, instead of opening new popup, I am printing it in same window, from where the print is initiated.

Comment: I can reproduce this.  After clicking print, switch back to the parent window without clicking print/cancel in the popup.  The parent window is now locked out.  For instance, if you click the jsfiddle icon in the upper left, it won't navigate you until you click print/cancel in the child popup.

Comment: Other browsers this isn't an issue because they use the system print dialog which prevents interaction with the browser until you finish with the dialog.

Comment: @KennethIto I posted this issue on chromium website. You can [check it here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=343436)

Comment: I can reproduce this the same as Kenneth Ito. The parent page won't navigate to the JSFiddle homepage until I've cancelled the print dialog, but I can type into the Fiddle no problems. It's just navigation that doesn't work.

I have a similar problem on a web app of my own, and in my case it *does* block the whole parent tab from working (i.e. both navigation and controls) – at least for a few seconds anyway. Your example is the first time I've been able to see this anywhere other than my site though. Sorry I can't offer any help, but I'm glad I've found someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Actually, duh, it's just like you say. Using `window.print()` is what seems to cause this, which is why I haven't been able to reproduce this anywhere but my own app (until now). I haven't been looking at pages with their own print button. For me I do still have the problem for a few seconds when using Chrome's print menu, not `window.print()`, but then it eventually sorts itself out.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in Google Chrome and will be fixed in Chrome 36 according to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359627).